# AngularJS ng-model $scope in ng-repeat is undefined

Tags: angularjs

I apologize in advance if i'm not wording this properly. I have a textbox with `ng-model` inside an `ng-repeat` and when I try to get the textbox value it's always `undefined`. I just want it to display whatever I type in the corresponding textbox.

It seems to be an issue with the `$scope`, so how would I make the `$scope.postText` global or at the controller root level so it can be accessible?

Here's the JSFiddle to help clear things up: http://jsfiddle.net/stevenng/9mx9B/14/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your click expression you can reference the `postText` and access it in your `savePost` function. If this wasn't in an ng-repeat you could access the single `$scope.postText` successfully but [ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat) creates a new scope for each item.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/VnQqH/) is an updated fiddle.

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
   <strong>{{post}}</strong>
   <input type="text" ng-model="postText">
   <a href="#" ng-click="savePost(postText)">save post</a>
</div>

$scope.savePost = function(post){
   alert('post stuff in textbox: ' + post);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Renan that helps a lot. I got it working by passing in 2 objects like this '<a href="#" ng-click="savePost(post, postText)">save post</a>'. But using a simple 'this' is much better!

Comment: that works, but how to set the value via script? I am looking for something like $scope.postText = "abv"

Comment: If I understand your question one way is to use [ng-init](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit) to set the initial value for postText like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/VnQqH/128/). I'd prefer to change the data type being bound to include the post text like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/VnQqH/127/).

Answer (score 45):

As @Gloopy already stated, ng-repeat creates a new child scope for each item in your `posts` array.  Since each item of the `posts` array is a primitive (a string), ng-repeat also creates a `post` property on each child scope, and assigns each of them the appropriate value from the array.  Inside the ng-repeat block is `ng-model="postText"`.  This creates a postText property on each of the child scopes.  Here is what that all looks like (for 2 of the 4 child scopes):

[image: ng-repeat scopes]

When a user types some text into one of the input textboxes, the appropriate gray box will store the text.  (E.g., the 2nd (from the top) gray box will store text a user types into the "tech" textbox.)  The parent scope cannot see the postText properties in the child scope -- this is the problem you had.  There are three common solutions:

1. @Gloopy's answer: define a function on the parent scope (which the child scopes can access, because ng-repeat child scopes prototypically inherit from the parent scope) and pass the child scope property value (i.e., postText's value) up to the parent.
2. Use objects instead of primitives in your `posts` array.  E.g.,
   `$scope.posts = [ {type: 'tech'}, {type: 'news'}, ...];`
   Then in your ng-repeat loop, use
   `<input type="text" ng-model="post.postText">`
   Because each array item is an object (and not a primitive), each child scope gets a reference to the appropriate object in array `posts`, rather than a copy (of a value).  Therefore, `post.postText` gets created on parent $scope property `posts`, and hence it is visible to the parent scope.  (So, in this case the child scopes would simply call `savePost()` -- there would be no need to pass any values up to the parent scope.)
   In other words, if a user typed "this is tech related" into the first text box, the `posts` array in the parent would be automatically updated as follows:
   `$scope.posts = [ {type: 'tech', postText: 'this is tech related'}, {type: 'news'}, ...];`
   One last note: the postText property is not added to the posts object until the user types something.
3. Use `ng-model="$parent.someProperty"` to bind the form element to a property on the parent scope, rather than on the child scope.  This solution would be difficult to implement for your scenario, and it is a rather fragile solution, as it depends on the HTML structure for scope inheritance... but I mention it for completeness.

(A fourth solution was presented by @Renan in comments on @Gloopy's answer.  This is a like solution 1., but with a variation: `this` is used instead of passing a value up to the parent. I'm not a fan of this approach as it makes it difficult to determine which $scope is being accessed or modified.  I think it is better that functions defined on $scope only access and modify their own $scope.)

For more information (and lots more pictures) about how prototypal scope inheritance works in Angular, see [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs)

Comment: I'm not seeing how in 2 you can call savePost() without passing anything. How would you refer to a specific child scope without passing the child object or index?

Comment: @Dean, good point.  You could loop through `posts` and determine which one(s) changed (e.g., if you wanted just one "save" button).  Or you could pass `post.type` as an argument, if you wanted a "save post" link for each post.

Comment: The diagram could be even better if you diagrammed the part about the ParentScope not being able to see the text typed into the boxes.  Draw a red line or some other way to show that things entered in the box aren't visible to the Parent.

Comment: @MarkRajcok I've a similar situation where I use ng-repeat on an array of objects (invoices). Each repeated invoice has an input field that populates another child array of objects (invoice-lines) inside the parent invoice. I also need to clear the textbox after adding the invoice-line. What I do now is, apart from the invoice-line array in invoice, I also have a temporary invoice-input property in invoice which I bind using ng-model='invoice.invoice-input'. I then clear this after I add the invoice-line to the invoice.invoice-lines array. Is this the correct approach for this situation?

Comment: @Tru, you should create a new Stack Overflow question/post and show your current design/code.  Then multiple people can critique it and offer suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a late answer. Please refer this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/X5gd2/
Please refer to the firebug's console, when u click on the links after typing some texts in the text box. The idea is to have a itemcontroller for each of the view that is repeated inside the ng-repeat.

The item controller:

```
function postItemController($scope){
    $scope.savePost = function(){
        console.log($scope.postText + " which belongs to " + $scope.post +" will be saved")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the model up into heading and value

```
angular.module('MyApp',[]);

function PostCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.posts = [{heading:'tech',value:''}, {heading:'news',value:''},     {heading:'sports',value:''},{heading:'health',value:''}];

    $scope.savePost = function(post){
        alert( 'post stuff in textbox: ' + post);
    }
}
```

HTML below..

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="PostCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
          <strong>{{post.heading}}</strong>
          <input type="text" ng-model="post.value"> 
          <a href="#" ng-click="savePost(post.value)">save post</a>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Check out this Fiddle..](http://jsfiddle.net/m075vx07/)