# AngularJS ng-model $scope in ng-repeat is undefined if update from outside ng-repeat $scope is also undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was looking this example [AngularJS ng-model $scope in ng-repeat is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11752977/3843405) in this question first answered by @Gloopy here http://jsfiddle.net/VnQqH/128/

My question is can I update **ng-model** values in **ng-repeat scope** from outside of **ng-repeat scope** like this:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="PostCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
      <strong>{{post}}</strong>
      <input type="text" ng-model="postText"> 

    </div>

    /*Update ng-model values (in ng-repeat scope) using single click*/

    <a href="#" ng-click="savePost(postText)">save post</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is controller:

```
angular.module('MyApp',[]);

function PostCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.posts = ['tech', 'news', 'sports', 'health'];
   $scope.savePost = function(post){
    alert( 'post stuff in textbox: ' + post);
   }
}
```

I tried but got undefined :( My experimental fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/hot81o2z/ If anyone has the solution for this problem please share. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: have you used $parent in this case?

Comment: No I haven't used $parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of $parent in order to pass a scope variable outside of the ng-repeat directive, something like this

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="PostCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
          <strong>{{post}}</strong>
          <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.postText"> 

        </div>
       <!--Update on single click-->
        <a href="#" ng-click="savePost(postText)">save post</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller: Not changed anything, kept what you had

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hot81o2z/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply it works but in that case ng-model values in all post taking same. Don't you think it should different.

Comment: then you need to have different scope variables

Comment: Could you please impletment it in your working demo. I am little confuse. Thanks!!!