# Submitting data in AngularJS form using ng-model inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752977/angularjs-ng-model-scope-in-ng-repeat-is-undefined), but the solutions there do not work for me.

I'm learning AngularJS and I am struggling to submit form data using `ng-model` inside of `ng-repeat`. I have a list of members of a group and the date they last attended:

```
[{"name": "Bob", "attended": "01/01/16"},
{"name":"Steve", "attended": "02/01/16"}]
```

I'm listing out all members using `ng-repeat`, and would like to be able to update the "attended" field from a form in each line. However, I cannot get "attended" to bind properly. Here's the code:

```
<div ng-repeat="member in members">
    {{member.name}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="attended"></input>
    <a href="#" ng-click="setAttended(attended)">Save</a>
</div>

$scope.setAttended = function(attended){
        alert( 'Date: ' + attended);
};
```

The alert shows "Date: undefined". I've also tried using objects instead of primitives:

```
<div ng-repeat="member in members">
    {{member.name}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="member.attended"></input>
    <a href="#" ng-click="setAttended(member)">Save</a>
</div>

$scope.setAttended = function(member){
        alert( 'Date: ' + member.attended);
};
```

I get that `ng-repeat` will create a new scope for each object, and those scopes inherit `setAttended` from the parent scope. I get that the parent scope doesn't know what is happening in the child scopes, and so the parameter must let it know.

Why doesn't my parameter contain my input value?

Is the input not being bound to the model correctly before I run `setAttended`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is working for me. See the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>



  <style>
  </style>

</head>


<body ng-controller="myController">


  <div ng-repeat="member in members">
    {{member.name}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="member.attended"/>
    <a href="#" ng-click="setAttended(member)">Save</a>
  </div>


  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
      $scope.members = [{
        "name": "Bob",
        "attended": "01/01/16"
      }, {
        "name": "Steve",
        "attended": "02/01/16"
      }];

      $scope.setAttended = function(member) {
        alert('Date: ' + member.attended);
      }

    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're right, it does work. Turns out the problem was the JQuery datepicker I'm using on the field. If I select a date from the datepicker, the model doesn't update. If I select a date then type anything in the field manually, it updates the model.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code and feedback me:

```
<div ng-repeat="member in members">
    {{member.name}}
    <input type="text" ng-model="members[$index].attended"></input>
    <a href="#" ng-click="setAttended(members[$index].attended)">Save</a>
</div>

$scope.setAttended = function(attended){
        alert( 'Date: ' + attended);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` , It refers to the correct `scope` object from `ng-repeat` function

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.members = [{"name": "Bob", "attended": "01/01/16"},
{"name":"Steve", "attended": "02/01/16"}];
   $scope.setAttended = function(member){
            alert( 'Date: ' + this.attended);
    };
});
```

```html
 <script data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-require="angular.js@1.4.x"></script>
    
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <div ng-repeat="member in members">
        {{member.name}}
        <input type="text" ng-model="attended">
        <a href="#" ng-click="setAttended(member)">Save</a>
    </div>
  </body>
```